# Node Socket.io on HA Proxy with multiple end points

Tags: node.js, sockets, load-balancing, haproxy

I am tying to deploy my node websocket service on two boxes and masking it using haproxy but its not working.

```
frontend http-in
  mode http
  bind *:80

  acl is_websocket path_beg /prodSocket                                                                     
  acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket
  acl is_websocket hdr_beg(Host) -i ws
  use_backend prodSocket if is_websocket

  acl is_websocket path_beg /demoSocket                                                                     
  acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket
  acl is_websocket hdr_beg(Host) -i ws
  use_backend demoSocket if is_websocket

backend demoSocket
  timeout server 180s
  server 148.251.76.84 148.251.76.84:9000 weight 1 maxconn 1024 check


backend prodSocket
  timeout server 180s
  server 148.251.76.85 148.251.76.85:9000 weight 1 maxconn 1024 check
```

Client code -

```
 var socket = io('http://localhost/prodSocket', {                                                            
      'force new connection': false,
      'reconnection delay': 500,
      'max reconnection attempts': 10,
 });
 socket.emit('client', { my: 'data' });
 socket.on('news', function (data) {
     console.log(data);
});
```

The above code does not work but if I make following changes it works -

```
frontend http-in
  mode http
  bind *:80

  acl is_websocket path_beg /socket.io                                                                     
  acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket
  acl is_websocket hdr_beg(Host) -i ws
  use_backend socket if is_websocket

backend socket
  timeout server 180s
  server 148.251.76.84 148.251.76.84:9000 weight 1 maxconn 1024 check
```

Client code -

```
 var socket = io('http://localhost:9090', {                                                            
      'force new connection': false,
      'reconnection delay': 500,
      'max reconnection attempts': 10,
 });
 socket.emit('client', { my: 'data' });
 socket.on('news', function (data) {
     console.log(data);
});
```

I understood that socket io is calling /socket.io endpoint for creating a socket connection but how can then deploy my service over two different end points ?

Versions -

1. Socket.io - 1.4.5
2. Node - v5.6.0
3. HAproxy -  1.4.24
4. Ubuntu - 14.04

HAProxy Log using /socket.io endpoint -

config -

```
frontend http-in
  mode http
  bind *:9090

  acl is_websocket path_beg /socket.io
  acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket                                                               
  acl is_websocket hdr_beg(Host) -i ws
  use_backend socket if is_websocket
```

CLient script -

```
 var socket = io('http://localhost:9090', {                                                 
      'force new connection': false,
      'reconnection delay': 500,
      'max reconnection attempts': 10,
 });


Jul 21 10:50:04 localhost haproxy[11981]: 127.0.0.1:48571 [21/Jul/2016:10:49:51.830] http-in socket/148.251.76.84 0/0/171/676/12725 101 187 - - ---- 2/2/2/2/0 0/0 "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=PvK2vnQO1_IepDHOAAAJ HTTP/1.1"
Jul 21 10:50:55 localhost haproxy[11981]: 127.0.0.1:48573 [21/Jul/2016:10:49:51.832] http-in socket/148.251.76.84 0/0/123/126/63531 200 1551 - - cD-- 2/2/2/2/0 0/0 "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LOBvKmM&sid=PvK2vnQO1_IepDHOAAAJ HTTP/1.1"
Jul 21 10:50:55 localhost haproxy[11981]: 127.0.0.1:48569 [21/Jul/2016:10:49:51.505] http-in socket/148.251.76.84 0/0/152/159/64144 200 1199 - - cD-- 1/1/1/1/0 0/0 "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LOBvKhF HTTP/1.1"
```

HAProxy Log using /prodSocket endpoint -

Config -

```
frontend http-in
mode http
bind *:9090

acl is_websocket path_beg /prodSocket
acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket                                                               
acl is_websocket hdr_beg(Host) -i ws
use_backend socket if is_websocket
```

CLient script -

```
 var socket = io('http://localhost:9090/prodSocket', {                                                 
      'force new connection': false,
      'reconnection delay': 500,
      'max reconnection attempts': 10,
 });


Jul 21 10:55:11 localhost haproxy[12361]: Proxy socket started.
Jul 21 10:55:11 localhost haproxy[12361]: 127.0.0.1:48856 [21/Jul/2016:10:55:11.767] http-in http-in/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 503 213 - - SC-- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LOBwYtK HTTP/1.1"
Jul 21 10:55:16 localhost haproxy[12362]: 127.0.0.1:48859 [21/Jul/2016:10:55:16.229] http-in http-in/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 503 213 - - SC-- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LOBwZz3 HTTP/1.1"
Jul 21 10:55:17 localhost haproxy[12362]: 127.0.0.1:48860 [21/Jul/2016:10:55:17.364] http-in http-in/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 503 213 - - SC-- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LOBwaEn HTTP/1.1"
Jul 21 10:55:19 localhost haproxy[12362]: 127.0.0.1:48862 [21/Jul/2016:10:55:19.075] http-in http-in/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 503 213 - - SC-- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LOBwafV HTTP/1.1"
Jul 21 10:55:22 localhost haproxy[12362]: 127.0.0.1:48865 [21/Jul/2016:10:55:22.262] http-in http-in/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 503 213 - - SC-- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LOBwbRI HTTP/1.1"
Jul 21 10:55:27 localhost haproxy[12362]: 127.0.0.1:48869 [21/Jul/2016:10:55:27.271] http-in http-in/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 503 213 - - SC-- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LOBwcfa HTTP/1.1"
```

Comment: "does not work" is not exactly a sufficient description of the problem.   What's in the HAProxy log?  One obvious problem is your ACLs.  ACLs are *lists* of possible conditions, and evaluate to `true` if *any* condition matches.  They are `OR`, not `AND`, and `use_backend ... if ...` referencing the same ACL more than once?  That makes no sense.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot when I use /socket.io as end point in haproxy it works (server and client can excthange messages) but when I change endpoints to anything else client and server can not emit and receive messages. i tried checking connected status for socket but which shows false and so

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot also even when I keep single acl rule and endpoint point other than socket.io it doest not work. Sever and client can not exchange messages.

Comment: Please help @Michael-sqlbot.. I am in  problem here

Comment: Enable logging for HAProxy and see what the log shows.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot i have posted the logs

Comment: That's much better.  Error 503 and `SC--` indicates that HAProxy isn't able to connect to the back-end, or didn't try because the back-end was not passing its health checks.  Use the stats page or stats socket to verify that the back-end is being declared "up" and troubleshoot from there.  My first guess is that the back-end is only listening on 127.0.0.1, the loopback adapter, so is only accessible from the machine where it is running.  It needs to listen on all addresses, usually configured as 0.0.0.0 or *.